# What is the suggested way for DAG config file in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

We are looking for the best approach for setting up the configuration file for each DAG, I know we can use JSON in Variable, but want to see if there are suggested approaches in Airflow or other format (i.e.YAML). Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Did you get an answer to this question?

Comment: @Priyesh not really, we end up using YAML and to build the configuration file and it works fine for our use case.

Comment: Yes. We are using environment variables as part of  config and those are loaded from a conf.env file.

Answer (score 1):

`YAML` it's a good combination between human-readbility and a good document storage format.